# Loop whole word 2007 document using vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am working on a user form for finding specific phrases and commenting them according to certain criteria. I have trouble adding comments for all found phrases in the document. It only changes the first found phrase although it selects all occurrences of the phrase. How can i modify this code for the whole content?

Here is my code:

```
 If Criteria2 <> "" Then
        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = Criteria2
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindAsk
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .Execute
        End With
       On Error Resume Next
        With Selection
            .Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Text:="SPE 2"
        End With
End If
```

---

Ok Here is the new code and it is not working as expected:

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        With Selection.Find
           .Text = CritArray(i)
           .Replacement.Text = ""
           .Forward = True
           .Wrap = wdFindContinue
           .Format = False
           .MatchCase = False
           .MatchWholeWord = False
           .MatchWildcards = False
           .MatchSoundsLike = False
           .MatchAllWordForms = False
           Do
               .Execute
               If Not .Found Then
                Exit Do
               ElseIf .Found Then
                FoundCount = FoundCount + 1
                Selection.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Text:=MessArray(i) & CritArray(i) & "' - found for the" & Str(FoundCount) & ". time"
               End If
            Loop 
        End With
```

What I get when using this as input:

```
Testrow1
Testrow2
```

is the following:

```
Testrow1 ....................................'Testrow1' - found for the 1. time
Testrow2 ....................................'Testrow2' - found for the 2. time
                                             'Testrow2' - found for the 1. time
```

I cannot understand why this is happening since the do .. loop should exit if nothing is found. Is it possible that .Wrap = wdFindContinue is the problem? There are three possibilities here:

- wdFindAsk ... asks at the end of document to search again at the beginning (don't want this)
- wdFindContinue ... searches without asking
- wdFindStop ... stops when it first finds the search phrase (don't want this)

Anybody got a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change it to:

```
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Although having just looked at your answer again (sorry!), do you want to add a comment in for every occurrence changed? As for this, you will have to do loop through each one with

```
Do
    ' .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne if you want to loop AND replace
    .Execute
    If Not .Found Then Exit Do
    Selection.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Text:="SPE 2"
Loop Until Not .Found
```

adding the comment until all are found/replaced.

Comment: Hi,I tried your suggestions with the following results: The first replaced the phrase with empty string like defined - I do not want this. The second worked but added six comments for five selections - last one twice.

Comment: I think I was thrown by the .Replacement.Text = "" in your code, I thought you were trying to replace them, my bad... Code edited to correct this, sorry!

Comment: Do you know why the loop inserts six comments instead of five?

Comment: Hi,I tested the code some more and still have the problem that it adds to many comments. I changed .Wrap to wdFindContinue. The first found criteria is counted correctly but the result of the second found criteria is always one more and then two comments are added.

Answer (score 0):

I used now the exact same loop and it works. The new code respectively old code:

```
For i = 0 To UBound(CritArray)
    With Selection
    .HomeKey wdStory
        With .Find
        .ClearFormatting
            Do While .Execute(FindText:=CritArray(i), _
            Forward:=True)

                Select Case i
                    Case 0: FoundCountC1 = FoundCountC1 + 1
                    Case 1: FoundCountC2 = FoundCountC2 + 1
                    Case 2: FoundCountC3 = FoundCountC3 + 1
                    Case 3: FoundCountC4 = FoundCountC4 + 1
                    Case 4: FoundCountC5 = FoundCountC5 + 1
                    Case 5: FoundCountC6 = FoundCountC6 + 1
                    Case 6: FoundCountC7 = FoundCountC7 + 1
                    Case 7: FoundCountC8 = FoundCountC8 + 1
                    Case 8: FoundCountC9 = FoundCountC9 + 1
                End Select

            Loop
        End With
    End With
Next
```